# Browse products - search results page

Tags: usability, search, search-results, browse

I'm having some trouble thinking of a way to present a browse products feature on the search results page. The main problem is how best to display a product which sits in two different categories. Here's an example of the product taxonomy:

```
All products > Sports & fitness > Bag

All products > Men's accessories > Bag
```

This feature should allow a user to view both it's parent nodes, and it's child nodes. Here are some of the ideas I had to display this information.

[image]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use [breadcrumbs](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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) to shot the path your user took (and so, letting them manage how they can come back to previous part of your shopping).

[Google](https://your.googlemerchandisestore.com/SubCategory/Women/Apparel/New%20in) online shopping store use a dropdown menu from top with the breadcrumbs techniques. You're sure that your users know where they are and how they can go back to previous part of the shopping website that way.

[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_16225016011_nr_n_2?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=i%3Avideogames-intl-ship%2Cn%3A%2116225016011%2Cn%3A6469269011&bbn=16225016011&ie=UTF8&qid=1544003846&rnid=16225016011) Implement both of them, but the dropdown menu come from the left side and the breadcrumbs is not exactly presented the same way (using more "human" language to show the user how he got here).

My opinion : Take inspiration from those. Combine breadcrumbs in a way that your users can understand it (Amazon is for everyone, google merchandise store is maybe more for "Tech Addict" people?) and dropdown menu that stays. This way, you'll never lost anybody and they can navigate through your shopping website the way they want (Autonomy in [Self-Determination Theory](http://selfdeterminationtheory.org/)) to find what they want (Competency)

Never forget to test what you're trying out to see if your design is adapted to your users! (if they're tech addict, show them this in a way that they are used to!)